# Manifolds Resulting from Gluing Tori

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I'm trying to show that if solid tori $T_1, T_2; T_i=S^1 \times D^2$ ,are glued by  homeomorphisms  between their respective boundaries, then the homeomorphism type of the identification space depends on the choice of homeomorphism up to, I think, isotopy ( Please forgive the rambling; I'm trying to put together a lot of different things from different sources, and I don't yet have a very coherent general picture.) I first thought of Lens spaces, but the gluing here is not done by a homeomorphism.

I have some fuzzy ideas here that I would like to make precise: I know this has to see with Heegard splittings; specifically, this is a genus-1 splitting ( actually, genus-1 gluing ) and the gluing may be determined by a mapping in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, which determines the induced map on the top homology , and different induced maps would result in different homeomorphic types on the glued spaces.

I think we can also see this from the perspective of Dehn surgery ( please feel free to correct anything I write here ), where we remove a link  $L$ and a tubular 'hood $T(L)$ of $L$ , and then glue another torus. I know then an n-framing is equivalent to removing a solid torus, twisting n times and then regluing.  But it's obvious from the post that I don't know how to show that the homeomorphism class of the space glued along $h: \partial T_1 \rightarrow \partial T_2$ depends on $h$.

Thanks, and sorry for the rambling ( not my fault, I was born a rambling man.)

Comment: I don't have enough points to write this as a comment, so here it goes as an answer; please feel free to move this as a comment if this is the protocol, and my apologies.
I think both $S^3$ and $S^2 \times S^1 $ can be obtained by gluing solid tori ( I'm sure
this is possible for $S^3$ ), and I think $S^2 \times S^1 $ results this way too, by using the identity as the gluing map, but I'm not 100%. And the two are definitely not homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: I am not quite sure you asked a question.

Comment: Lens spaces *can* be obtained by glueing two tori using a homeomorphism, actually (in fact, they are precisely the manifolds which can be obtained in this way!). Try to construct a projective space first, and generalize.

Comment: Are you asking the question "Isotopic maps yield homeomorphic manifolds"? Or, do you mean "there are non-homeomorphic manifolds obtained by gluing two solid tori"? Both have positive answers.

Comment: I just wanted to have either an example of different gluing homeomorphisms producing different manifolds, or an argument to show this, and an argument for why isotopic homeos. produce the same homeomorphism type. Lens spaces are usually defined in terms of group actions, and not explicitly as gluing maps.

Answer (score 1):

To see that isotopic maps produce homoeomorphic manifolds, consider the manifold given by 
$$D^2 \times S^1 \cup_f S^1 \times S^1 \times I \cup_g D^2 \times S^1.$$
If $f$ and $g$ are isotopic, then omitting either the first or the second term produces a space homeomorphic to a solid torus rel boundary, so the whole thing is homeomorphic to either gluing.

In the other direction, if you believe $S^2 \times S^1$ and $S^3$ are not homeomorphic, either of these is relatively easy to produce (e.g. $S^3 = \{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1\} = \{x^2 + y^2 \le 1/2\} \cup \{z^2+w^2 \le 1/2\}$).

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide here two different objects that can be obtained by gluing two solid tori.

Before start, let me fix a notation that $T_1$, $T_2$ be two solid tori $S^1 \times D^2$ and $f : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ be a map from $\partial T_1$ to $\partial T_2$, along which we glue two solid tori.

First, $S^3$ is obtained when $f$ is a map $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$. To see this, let us first delete a meridian disk $D_M$ from $T_1$ and then glue $T_1 \setminus D_M$ and $T_2$ by $f(x, y) = (y, x)$. It results in a 3-ball, then gluing $D_M$ again produces $S^3$.

The other thing we can have is $S^2 \times S^1$, which is realized when $f$ is an identity. Note first that $S^2 \times S^1$ is obtained by identifying two boundary components of $S^2 \times [0, 1]$. Taking a circle $C \subset S^2$, $C \times [0, 1]$ becomes a torus after identifying two boundary components $S^2 \times \{0\}$ and $S^2 \times \{1\}$. We can now drill out this torus from $S^2 \times S^1$, which makes us get two solid tori with boundary $C \times S^1$.